# What is k in RSA?

Tags: rsa, public-key, algorithm-design, terminology

I am currently learning about RSA since I didn't understand the public-key-system but now I am… kind of. So I am writing the numbers as follows:

$p = prime\ number\\  
q = prime\ number\\ 
N = Public\ Key\ (p \times q)\\
Z = \phi(N)\\
E = Public\ exponent\\
D = Private\ key$

Now, to calculate $D$, the private key, you need the following formula:

$$D=\frac{ k \times (\phi(N))) +1 }{ E }$$

Can someone please explain me what $k$ means?

Answer (score 3):

$\big(\hspace{-0.03 in}$You don't need that. $\:$ $\operatorname{L}\hspace{-0.02 in}\operatorname{cm}\hspace{.02 in}(\hspace{.04 in}p\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.05 in}1,\hspace{-0.02 in}q\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.05 in}1)$ can be used instead of $\phi(N)$.$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)$

$k$ is an integer which will make the quotient an integer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: How do you choose, calculate it?

Comment: You go to the "Computation" section of the page I linked to. $\;$

Comment: Is it what I think it means: When the division above(without k) happens to be not an integer but some number with decimal places. k will multiply it so it becomes a round, integer?

Comment: No, since the image should have an open-parenthesis just before the $k$. $\;$

Comment: `No, since the image should have an open-parenthesis just before the k.` I just edited the question, replacing that image with MathJax. Doing so, I reproduced the open-parenthesis error to make sure the question remained unchanged and nothing breaks. Please feel invited to correct the formula if you think it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's a translation of $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(N)}$, namely that $e$ and $d$ are each other's inverse modulo $\phi(N)$, which says that $ed-1$ must be an integer multiple of $\phi(N)$ (recall that $a \equiv b \pmod{c}$ iff $c$ divides $b-a$ in the integers iff $b-a=lc$ for some integer $l$) and some some $k \in \Bbb Z$ exists with $k\phi(N) = ed-1$ (as an equation in $\Bbb Z$) and this translates to your formula via some elementary rewriting.

So the actual value of $k$ is quite irrelevant (and need not be stored or remembered when using or implementing RSA), but this analysis is done before the Wiener/Coppersmith small $d$-attack (via continued fractions or lattices), IIRC. It's a necesary auxiliary unknown in the RSA-system of equations, as it were.

Answer (score 0):

*DE= 1 mod (ϕ(N))* so *D=(k×(ϕ(N)))+1)/E*  with k is 1, 2, 3...
The private k D can be computed efficiently by using the Extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Have a look at [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for better formatting.

Answer (score -1):

*k* is not actually needed as you only need to find d.just leave *k* and calculate and multiply it by a number which will be k to make it an integer

Comment: This answer is rather unintelligible to me, especially the last sentence. You're welcome to answer questions here, but please put in the effort and format your questions well. Then reread them as if you are the person that asked the question; would this be easy to understand? That kind of effort is required to create good answers.

Comment: @datboi  Please edit your response.